# Load css on controller function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, pagination

i have problem on load asset css(bootstrap and image) on pagination php
my main / default page is 
and of course the image and css is loaded

> http://localhost:8080/iklan/

....

but when i entered page 2 into..

> http://localhost:8080/iklan/iklan/index/2

the image and the css bootstrap wont show

...
maybe it because the function index controller
 `$config["base_url"] = base_url().'/iklan/index';`

my css is on asset

> C:\xampp\htdocs\iklan\aset

while my image is on

> C:\xampp\htdocs\iklan\upload_iklan

and i call css on view like this 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="aset/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

anyone know how to load the css?

Comment: Try changing `$config['base_url']` to `base_url().'/index';`

Comment: unfortunately it become "Object not found!" or "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: Where are the css files located? how do you call it on your html code?

Comment: on : C:\xampp\htdocs\iklan\aset
.
my views on : C:\xampp\htdocs\iklan\application\views
.
and i call it like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="aset/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your base url from

$config["base_url"] = base_url().'/iklan/index';

to

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('/iklan/index');

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>aset/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: OH THANK ALOT FROM YOU... THIS IS WORKED.. MAY GOD BLESS YOU

Comment: LOL im so happy

Comment: Thanks.God bless you

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

First set ur `base url` in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/iklan/';
```

and load `css` and `js` by using `site_url()`;

**`site_url()`** returns your site URL, as specified in your config file. The index.php file will be added to the URL automatically

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('aset/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" >
```

**Note** : make sure your css file path is correct

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: yep this is worked too. thank for helping me :).
just used "href="<?=site_url" haha